# Resource leak: 'input' is never closed in vscode

Tags: java

Why does vs code give me the warming "Resource leak: 'input' is never closed" in the following code?
My code runs correctly but still gives this error.
problem in (ln 5,col 17)

```
package JAVA;
import java.util.Scanner;
public class FirstProgram2 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Enter the first number: ");
        int num1 = input.nextInt();
        System.out.print("Enter the second number: ");
        int num2 = input.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Before swapping:");
        System.out.println("First number: " + num1);
        System.out.println("Second number: " + num2);
        // Swapping the numbers
        int temp = num1;
        num1 = num2;
        num2 = temp;
        System.out.println("After swapping:");
        System.out.println("First number: " + num1);
        System.out.println("Second number: " + num2);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

`Scanner` is a `Closable`, so your IDE correctly recognizes that you've opened it but haven't explicitly called `close()` on it when you're done with it, so there's a theoretical resource leak here.

However, in this case, `input` is a `Scanner` based on `System.in`, which you should never close explicitly.

To make a long story short, you should dismiss this warning.

Answer (score 0):

`Scanner` implements the `Closeable` interface, i.e. it has a method called `close`. You would have to guarantee, that this will always be called as otherwise this might lead to memory-leaks as your IDE is suggesting here..
In its most explicit way, this would look like this:

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
try {
   << do your stuff>>
} catch (Exception ex) {
   <<Handle exception>>
} finally {
   scanner.close();
}
```

However, it is also AutoCloseable, which allows this convenience solution:

```
try(Scanner scanner = new Scanner()) {
   << do your stuff>>
} catch (Exception ex) {
   <<Handle exception>>
}
```

Here you don't have to call close() explicitly anymore as Java will already do this as you are creating the Scanner in the try.

The term you might want to look at if you are more interested is "try-with-resources"

Comment: `Closeable` is a specialization of `AutoCloseable`, so your argument is a bit weird IMO (that is, considering `AutoCloseable` and `Closeable` separately).

Comment: BTW closing `System.in` most often is not recommended - and closing the `Scanner` using `System.in` as source, will also close it aswell